# Function to standardize matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance

I'm attempting to write a function that will standardize an n by d matrix, i.e. the matrix will be $N(0,I)$

From my understanding, a matrix Z can be "standardized" through the following operation: Z  = $\Sigma^{-1/2}(X-a)\sim N(0,I)$, where a is a matrix of the row means of matrix X, and $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ is the square root of the inverse of the covariance matrix.

The function below attempts to take a matrix and standardize it:

```
standardize<-function(X){
   Sigma<-cov(X)
   S<-svd(Sigma)
   R<-S$u%*%diag(sqrt(S$d))%*%t(S$v)
   R.inverse<-solve(R)
   Z<-X-rowMeans(X)
   Z.final<-R.inverse%*%t(Z)
}
```

However, the resulting matrix usually has several NaNs values after attempting to compute the square root of the inverse of the covariance matrix.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you try to do? `standardized = (Z-mean(Z))/sd(Z)`

Comment: I don't think that will work. We want the matrix to have the row means as 0 and the covariance matrix to be the identity matrix. That won't work.

Comment: What is the language in which this script is written ?

Comment: `R` I think, @st

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes in R

Comment: There is a few issues. First, your matrix might not be invertible. Hence why you get NaNs. Second, you don't take the elementwise square root. It's a matrix square root you need.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes you're right. I will update the equation with my attempt using singular value decomposition. However, the resulting covariance matrix still appears to be incorrect.